# Last word penalty

Tags: typography, hyphenation

Is there a way to specify penalty *only* to the last word of a paragraph?

`\righthyphenmin=3` sets, for instance, 3 letters as a minimum at the beginning of a  line. On the other hand, `\finalhyphendemerits=500000` avoids a hyphen at the next to last line, no matter how long this might be. Instead of this penalty, I would prefer to avoid only ending lines with, say, less than 5 characters.

Comment: Perhaps you can get ideas from `impnattypo`.

Comment: There's no such thing in legacy TeX. You can do it with LuaTeX.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using LaTeX, the following code should help:

```
\setlength{\parfillskip}{2ex plus \dimexpr\linewidth-2\parindent}
```

Using this, you are telling LaTeX to leave white-space of at least `2ex` and at most `linewidth-2\parindent` at the end of a paragraph. In this case, it means that anything on the last line of the paragraph has to be at least `2\parindent`, which greatly reduces the chance of there being a hyphen (I have never had one using that setting and proper hyphenation penalties). it also prevents your line from being shorter than the next paragraph's indent, which would be ugly.